# Lock on some data error in mobile first 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am working with mobile first application and I have set it locally. I left server idle for about 15 minutes and then it is gives me configuration error.

When then I deploy adapter below error get started coming and not getting stop and adapter is not getting deploy. 
**Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.**

I tried clean the server, projects, restart studio every thing.

I have changed the workspace three time.

1) Eclipse - Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600
2) Mobile first : 7.0.0.00-20160307 - 1716
3) OS : Windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.**

This is a common error or warning while server is downloading the artifacts(wlapp, adapter etc.) from database.

My actual problem was with database. WebSphere liberty with mobilefirst is giving derby as default database and My server was not working properly with it.

I changed it to MySQL database and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the Java process or restarting the computer. You should then be able to successfully start the server and deploy the adapter.

Comment: delete eclipse and install the plug-in again?

Comment: When I deleted server from workspace and trying so I am getting error : Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.
There might be a JMX configuration error: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: I didn't say delete the server. I said delete eclipse, use a new one and re-install the plug-in

Comment: I did the same thing you suggested for Luna and Kepler, It work a time. When I shutdown my laptop and start again, this error get starting to come.